# How do I use a custom RPC endpoint with Safe wallet

Tags: safe-core

I have noticed that in the last day or two that my Safe wallet has completely stopped working.

I've tracked it down to Infura being blocked. It is blocked on both that machine and the network it sits on because it is very heavily locked down. While Infura has been blocked for years, only in the last few days has it completely stopped Safe wallet from working.

I am unable to sign or reject any transactions, it just states a network error and asks me over and over to reconnect my wallet.

Now there is access to a local RPC node which I have configured in the Safe wallet settings, however that too isn't working, which I assume is due to a missing API on my execution node.

I have enabled `ETH,NET,WEB3,DEBUG` but Safe wallet seems to be unable to use this because every POST request that it sends to the node fails.

That same RPC endpoint works from that machine with Metamask, which is why I assume it is a missing API, because otherwise there is nothing stopping that machine from contacting that RPC node and getting the information that it needs.

The knowledge base mentions using an RPC node is possible, but it doesn't mention how to set this up or troubleshoot this, and when I asked in Discord they directed me to post my question to this age here, so I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the settings page `https://app.safe.global/settings/environment-variables`
2. Update your RPC endpoint
   [image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the main post, I have done this, but every API request to that RPC node errors out.

It says Method:Post, File:/, Initiator:fetch, Transferred:Mixed Block - And the Confirm and Reject buttons are still greyed out